# agregar un select a un modal

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

adjunto el modal por si alguin me puede ayudar thk es en el modal de prioridad

```
 ?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal20" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Agregar nueva incidencia</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_ticket" name="guardar_ticket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax"></div>
              <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prioridad" class="col-sm-3 control-label">prioridad</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prioridad" name="prioridad" placeholder="prioridad" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incidencia" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Incidencia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incidencia" name="incidencia" placeholder="incidencia" required>
            </div>
          </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tema" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asunto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tema" name="tema" placeholder="Asunto" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="detalle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Detalle</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea  class="form-control"  id="detalle" name="detalle" placeholder="Detalle" required></textarea>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imagen" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagen</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="imagen" type="file" name="imagen" > 
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Saludos te sugiero mires lo que pusiste y corrobores colocaste suficiente información que permita ayudarte. Me da la impresión que lo medular de tu idea a transmitir no la plasmaste. *¿"Agregar un select a modal para registrarlo"?*

Comment: ok gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, por favor puede explicar un poco mas donde quieres colocar el **select** y si lo colocaste que error envía. Otra cosa es  como quieres llenarlo desde una base de datos  o va hacer con valores fijos. Por favor si puede explicar un poco más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agregar un select solo debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="prioridad" class="col-sm-3 control-label">prioridad</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id="prioridad" name="prioridad" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione la prioridad</option>
            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
            <option value="Media">Media</option>
            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cabe resaltar que el valor de tu `<select>` es el valor que lleva el atributo `value` del `<option>` que haya sido seleccionado, y para capturar ese valor solo haces esto:

```
var prioridad = $("#prioridad").val();
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !